# Weird error about re Enabling a ToggleButton

Tags: android

I've a very strange problem,
i try to disable a toggle button for just a sec in order to make impossible for people in my application to spamclick it.

my toggleButton has this listener :

```
videoToggleListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                switchVideoSource();
                switchBetweenSources.setEnabled(false);

                freezeToggle.schedule(new TimerTask(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        switchBetweenSources.setEnabled(false);
                        switchBetweenSources.setEnabled(true);

                    }

                }, 1000);


            }
        };
```

my application doesn't force close on setEnabled(false) but do force close on setEnabled(true).

any idea ?

my log cat :

```
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:642)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:668)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5255)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.widget.TextView.invalidateDrawable(TextView.java:3916)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.invalidateDrawable(LayerDrawable.java:298)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:300)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.selectDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:227)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:99)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:400)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.onStateChange(LayerDrawable.java:409)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:400)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:7374)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.widget.TextView.drawableStateChanged(TextView.java:2312)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.drawableStateChanged(CompoundButton.java:265)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.widget.ToggleButton.drawableStateChanged(ToggleButton.java:143)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:7388)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at android.view.View.setEnabled(View.java:3147)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at fr.partisocialiste.psa.activity.VideosGridActivity$1$1.run(VideosGridActivity.java:101)
02-10 13:45:30.500: E/AndroidRuntime(7285):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
02-10 13:45:32.804: I/Process(7285): Sending signal. PID: 7285 SIG: 9
```

EDIT :

i've change my listener this way :

```
videoToggleListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                switchVideoSource();
                switchBetweenSources.setEnabled(false);

                freezeToggle.schedule(new TimerTask(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                switchBetweenSources.setEnabled(true);

                            }                               
                        });                         
                    }                   
                }, 2000);
            }
        };
```

Thanks everybody, you're awsome =) !

Comment: Are you sure error is only on   switchBetweenSources.setEnabled(true);
did you test commenting this line.

Comment: yes of course, that's what is weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the problem is that you try to alter a `View` from a non-UI thread. If you say that you don't get this exception on the first line inside the `TimerTask`, just in the second, this may be because your `ToggleButton` is already disabled, and this does not alter the `View`.

To change the state of the `View` from other `Thread` thant the UI Thread you should use `runOnUiThread()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update UI components from a background thread, which Android does not allow.

Look into creating a handler that acts as a *callback* so whenever the TimerTask fires, it triggers the handler that enables and disables the button (on the UI thread).